# How long do Claptrap's "High Five!" buffs last?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

One of Claptrap's end-of-tree skills allow the giving of high fives, which, upon succcessful high five, gives both participants a buff (+15% gun damage, +50% firerate and regenerate 3% max health "for a little while"). How long is "a little while"?

Comment: Also, apparently you get the buffs for a few seconds if nobody high fives you. Being ignored by friends bonus for the win!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**30 seconds**. The cooldown between high fives is 30 seconds, and the buffs seem to last that full cooldown time. Therefore, the "High Five!" buffs last 30 seconds.